# Creating a for loop that takes a manual sum of squares within and between groups

Tags: r, math, statistics

Per my lack of understanding of loops, I'm wondering how I might go about translating these two mathematical functions into R. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

My real confusion is more-so that I don't know how I might start coding a sum into R

Comment: Please show us whatever you've tried this far and what problems you've found. SO is a great place to help you solve code-related problems, but if you're after a coder, probably this is not the venue...

Comment: SO is not a good place to start learning how to code from the ground up, you are better off looking for a good tutorial/book that explains the basics and the concepts behind them, and then coming to SO when you have specific questions about code you have been trying to write during your learning process.

Comment: Did you just google something like "how to do a sum in R" ? That would probably lead you to some starting point. Then after some attempts you can search / or ask a more specific question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by trying to understand this

```
a = 1:100
mysum = 0
for (i in seq_along(a)){
  mysum = a[i] + mysum 
}
mysum
```

This code sums the numbers from 1:100